# Max OS Lion 10.7.3 DNS lookup very slow with MAMP

Tags: php, dns, osx-lion, mamp, ipv6

This question has been asked in many forms, and I have spent more than six hours scouring the internet for an answer that solves my problem. So far, I've been unsuccessful. I use MAMP to develop PHP applications, and I upgraded from Snow Leopard to Lion yesterday and immediately my local applications were running much slower. I believe that its a DNS lookup issue around how Lion handles IPv6. I tried the following steps to fix the problem:

1. Changed all of the entries in my host file to no longer use the .local TLD
2. Put all of the entries in my host file onto separate lines
3. Ensured that my host file had the correct encoding
4. Added IPv6 entries to all local entries in my host file
5. Installed dnsmasq (may have not done this correctly)
6. Put all of my host file entries before the fe80::1%lo0 localhost line

This fixed some problems, but there's still one problem that I haven't figured out. In our PHP applications, we define our SOAP endpoints like so:

> api:8080/contract/services/SomeService?wsdl

On each server, there is an "api" entry in the host file that points to the IP address for the SOAP API. So, when I want to point to our dev server, I change my hosts file to look like this:

> 132.93.1.4 api

(not a real IP)

The DNS lookup for the api entry in the host file still takes 5 seconds every time. When I ping api, the result comes back immediately. However, when I ssh api, it takes about 5 seconds before I can connect to the server. This means that when I load up my PHP application, any SOAP query will take 5 seconds + however long the actual query takes, making local development totally impossible. I realize that the way we're defining our endpoint may not be the best design decision, but it's what I have to work with.

From other questions I've read, I believe it's trying to look up "api" in IPv6 first, failing, and then looking in /etc/hosts. I tried using dnsmasq to switch this order, but had no luck. Does anybody know how to force it to read /etc/hosts first, or skip IPv6 altogether?

Update: I changed the entry in the hostfile to api.com, api.foo, anything with a "." in it, and it responded immediately. However, I would still like to find a solution that doesn't require changing the name "api".

Comment: The only solution I've had any success with is using an api pointer that has a "." in it. So instead of pointing "api" in my host file to the IP address of the API machine, I'm using "api.dev".

Comment: Thanks for the question. Basically the same issue over here with os x 10.8.2 and MAMP 2.1.1. The usual IPv6 trick (with Tabs) doesn't work. My only fix so far: Turn of WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issues ever since I upgraded my modem which supports IPv6. Adding both host name formats (IPv4 and IPv6) fixed the issue for:

```
::1 domain.dev # <== localhost on crack
127.0.0.1   domain.dev
```